# Python3 cursor.execute correct syntax

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, load-data-infile

Trying to insert some data using python3 and a local csv file - what is wrong with this syntax? python keeps saying

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ','' at line 1

```
cursor.execute("""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/mongo_exported_users.csv' INTO TABLE users IGNORE 1 LINES, FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), there can be no comma before the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause, and also, the `IGNORE # LINES` clause must come after the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause:

```
cursor.execute("""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/mongo_exported_users.csv'
    INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES""")
```

Comment: even so... _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','' at line 1

Comment: I see. Fixed then.

Comment: what changed? can you clarify?

Comment: As I added to my answer, "the `IGNORE # LINES` clause must come after the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` clause".

Comment: what other edge caes are there here? I tried adding an escaped by and now getting the same error even though ingore lines is last ``` ax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1
```

INTO TABLE gap.vdmUsers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES"""

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), where the proper syntax of the `LOAD DATA` statement is shown. `ESCAPED BY` is simply one of the options available to the `FIELDS` clause, so you should not write `FIELDS` again after the `TERMINATED BY` option. i.e. `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/mongo_exported_users.csv' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;`